# Alternative to the chart web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, chart

I am in charge of a SharePoint site for a team of writers, which we use to keep track of our topics (we have an extensive list of topics with their workflow status, version of the product, feature, etc).

I'd like to create some charts using the information from this list that give the writers an overview of their topics and how far they are in the writing process. For example, number of topics by status, number of topics by product/category/feature, number of topics by writer, and so on.

The charts web part used to solve this, but I understand that it has been removed. I am working in the Office 365 version of SharePoint and I'm not a developer. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use Excel charts/graph and publish it on SharePoint Online with Excel Services.  Check the links below:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-sharepoint-online-excel-services.html

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/BI-capabilities-in-Excel-and-Office-365-26c0548e-124c-4fd3-aab3-5f64568cb743

Comment: I've looked into this, but as far as I can make out, this would mean that I would have to keep the data in Excel up to date and not use the data from SharePoint. Is that correct? The charts have to be dynamically updated by the information from the SharePoint list or the won't be useful.

Comment: Assuming the data is maintained in a SharePoint List, you can export the list into Excel which will have the data connection with SharePoint List. So if you add data on SharePoint List and refresh in Excel you will have updated data. See this http://rippleeffect.com/2011/07/permanantly-link-data/ or  If you a developer you can also look at this: http://www.sites.se/2013/12/sharepoint-online-charts-office-365/,

Comment: Hmm - we don't work in Excel and this would mean having to constantly manually go in and update the Excel spreadsheet. What I'm looking for is charts that reflect the list in real time. Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't sound like the workaround that I was hoping for.

Comment: Then I think the only option is to custom built it something along the lines I have suggested in my earlier comment or use third party tools.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I thought. It's nice to have that confirmed. Do you have any idea of a third-party tool that's reliable?

Comment: Before you go down to third party tools, have a look at Power BI.  On the tools, I came across this http://www.spchart.com/.  I don't have any experience with this but it looks good.